# Как через Яндекс.Карты вывести в нужный мне input данные о месте по нажатию на карту?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, api, яндекс-карты, яндекс-карта-api

Есть пример взятый из песочницы https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/route_panel_control . Как вывести из инпута в левом верхнем углу название пункта в свой input (то есть из двух инпутов откуда и куда в input1 и input2 например). Пожалуйста в виде кода, ибо новичок совсем в этой технологии.

Answer (score 0):

Можно изменить этот пример, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку на карте получать состояние панели маршрутов и считывать из нее названия пунктов:

```js
ymaps.ready(function() {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.753994, 37.622093],
    zoom: 9,
    // Добавим панель маршрутизации.
    controls: ['routePanelControl']
  });

  var control = myMap.controls.get('routePanelControl');

  // Зададим состояние панели для построения машрутов.
  control.routePanel.state.set({
    // Выключим возможность задавать пункт отправления в поле ввода.
    fromEnabled: true,
    // Адрес или координаты пункта отправления.
    from: 'Санкт-Петербург',
    // Включим возможность задавать пункт назначения в поле ввода.
    toEnabled: true,
    // Адрес или координаты пункта назначения.
    to: 'Москва'
  });

  // Зададим опции панели для построения машрутов.
  control.routePanel.options.set({
    // Запрещаем показ кнопки, позволяющей менять местами начальную и конечную точки маршрута.
    allowSwitch: false,
    // Включим определение адреса по координатам клика.
    // Адрес будет автоматически подставляться в поле ввода на панели, а также в подпись метки маршрута.
    reverseGeocoding: true,
    // Зададим виды маршрутизации, которые будут доступны пользователям для выбора.
    types: {
      auto: true,
      masstransit: true,
      pedestrian: true,
      bicycle: true,
      taxi: true
    }
  });

  // Создаем кнопку, с помощью которой пользователи смогут получить начальную и конечную точки маршрута.
  var getPointsButton = new ymaps.control.Button({
    data: {
      content: "Получить значения",
      title: "Получить пункты маршрута"
    },
    options: {
      selectOnClick: false,
      maxWidth: 190
    }
  });
  // Объявляем обработчик для кнопки.
  getPointsButton.events.add('click', function() {
    $("#input1").val(control.routePanel.state.get('from'));
    $("#input2").val(control.routePanel.state.get('to'));

  });
  myMap.controls.add(getPointsButton);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>links</title>
 <style>
  html, body {
   width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;
  }
  #map {
   width: 100%; height: 70%; padding: 0; margin: 0;
  } </style>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&apikey=<ваш API-ключ>" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <form>
   Откуда:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="input1" readonly>
   <br/>
   Куда:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="input2" readonly>
   <br/>
  </form>
 </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
```